# How many relations can be defined the this power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations

Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$

What is the number of reflexive relations the can be defined on $P(A)$?

I first thought the number is 3, but it seems I'm wrong.

How can someone solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want the relation to be defined on $P(A)$?

Comment: Yes. I know how to calc the size of $P(A)$, I don't know how to calc the number of reflexive relations i can define there :S

Answer (score 1):

$$P(A) = \{\emptyset,1,2,3,\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$$
Now, a relation $R$ on a set $X$ is reflexive if for all $x \in X$, we have that $(x,x) \in R$. This means that any reflexive relation on $P(A)$ must *at least* contain the pairs
$$(\emptyset,\emptyset),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(\{1,2\},\{1,2\}),(\{2,3\},\{2,3\}),(\{1,3\},\{1,3\}),(\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,3\}).$$
How many subsets of $P(A) \times P(A)$ exist that contain these pairs?

Answer (score 1):

To extend mrp's answer: $|\mathcal P (A)\times\mathcal P (A)|=2^{2^3}=256.$ We take the $8$ pairs we are interested in, and put them into a bag. This bag is a relation. Now, we can add any other element of $\mathcal P (A) \times \mathcal P (A)$ and add it to our bag to create a new relation. This can be achieved in

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{256-8}\binom{256-8}{i}\tag{1}$$

ways. This is: the ways we can pick $i$ elements from the $256-8$ elements that are not the $8$ pairs we are interested in. This number of ways is the number of relations. So $(1)$ yields:

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{256-8}\binom{256-8}{i}1^i1^{256-8-i}=(1+1)^{256-8}.$$

Comment: I assume you mean $|\mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(A)| = 256$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I will correct that